# dynamic line styling in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I have some timeseries data with some missing values that I'd like to be able to draw in a chartjs line chart that looks as close as possible to the following picture.

[image: timeseries with missing data]

The difficult thing I find is the handling of the 'missing' values which in the image are represented by crosses with a dashed line around them.  In chartjs, the point style attributes (i.e. pointStyle and pointBorderColor) are scriptable so can be dynamically replaced with a cross for the 'missing' data but it seems the line attributes (i.e. the borderDash attribute) are not dynamically controllable (at least in 2.9.3 and 3.0.0alpha).  Have I missed something? 
 Is there another way of achieving the same visual effect?

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find fulfill this requirement, but was able to use insert null values between the interpolated 'missing' values to produce the following line chart:
[image]

Which was good enough for this scenario.